# blueimp jQuery File Upload error : file upload aborted

Tags: php, jquery, blueimp

I have a little problem with the blueimp's plugin, in localhost with wamp server, uplaod is great but now I am trying to install jquery upload in a debian 8 lamp server but when I try to upload a file UploadHandler.php returns:

> 'error: file upload aborted'.

I thought the problem was the level of authorisation so I did a command on all directories :

```
sudo -i chmod 777 /var/www/html
```

but it did not work; I did the same for upload directory:

```
sudo -i chmod 777 /var/www/html/server/php/files
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Are the answers to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064666/jquery-file-upload-always-fails-with-file-upload-aborted) any help?

Comment: No sir because upload works, but uploadHandler.php is not listing thé repertory content

Comment: And thé code i use is the same that in the .git repertory