# jQuery File Upload Always Fails With "File upload aborted"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I'm using [Blueimp File Upload Plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), to upload files to a remote server.

HTML:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="http://my-server-ip/upload.php" multiple>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        },
        paramName: 'files[]'
    });
});
```

So I try to upload a file, but I am always getting the following error: `File upload aborted`

As you can see, I tried to add the `paramName: 'files[]'` option like the answer on the following question: [Jquery File Upload always fails with File Upload Aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064666/jquery-file-upload-always-fails-with-file-upload-aborted), And the folder's permission is `777`.

Comment: What are you getting in `$_FILES` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre `Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1uploadMe.txt
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text/plain
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phphJD9Lu
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                )

        )

)`

Comment: It seems something is going wrong over server side...

Comment: @RayonDabre You were right, I checked the logs and I get `move_uploaded_file(...): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...` although the folder's permission is `777`. I run php5 and nginx on centos7. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps late, but hopefully this will help anyone else that encounters the file abort error.

In my case, I was uploading huge video files...2-10GB each.  After checking everything on the web about what was causing it, I found that the provided `UploadHandler.php` file didn't properly deal with file sizes beyond a 32-bit signed integer (2,147,483,647)  - so, when it compared that result with the actual files size uploaded, it didn't match and triggered the error.

Additionally, there's intermittent use of comparison with integers and strings, so I just changed the code to use (float) for anything related to file size, and that fixed everything.